# How to make unresponsive flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

This question sounds weird but what I'm trying to make doesn't require any responsiveness.

But designer, who I'm working with, uses 12 column grid system.

So its easy to use flexbox to make a 3/2/7 grid, like this:

`container: display:flex
a flex:3
b flex:2
c flex:7`

But its responsive by default.
I want to use flexbox to make sure my web-app stay in fractions of its flex based on its maximum browser size, maybe 1920x1080 or 2880x1800, and unresponsive. 
Is it possible with flexbox?

Comment: Does setting `min-width` on the container help?

Comment: @Richard oh, I think its what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: @Richard any idea how to make its min-width 100% based on user's resolution?

Comment: I think you'll need code to do that, unless the flex conatainer is a child of an element that is already the full width. I would start by hardcoding a fixed min-width to prove the approach works and then setting the actual client width. PS. sites that assume you run your browser maximised are really annoying: use browser width please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no CSS unit (yet) that knows the screen resolution, so you'll need a small script that fix that for you, here done by simply set the available screen width to the body on page load.

*As being said already, this usually brings a bad user experience and should be avoided if possible*

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  document.body.style.cssText = 'width: ' + window.screen.availWidth + 'px';

  /* for this demo only */
  console.log('This body takes full screen width and is', window.screen.availWidth + 'px wide');
})
```

```css
.flex { 
  display: flex;
}
.flex > div { 
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.flex > div ~ div { 
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.a { 
  flex: 3;
}
.b { 
  flex: 2;
}
.c { 
  flex: 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="a"> A </div>
  <div class="b"> B </div>
  <div class="c"> C </div>
</div>
```